# How can you dynamically change the property of a field attribute for a given data record?

Tags: acumatica

I need to change the property of a field attribute at runtime. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

**Way 1**

A straightforward way of doing it:

```
foreach (PXEventSubscriberAttribute attribute in cache.GetAttributes<Field>(dataRecord))
{
    PXSomeAttribute someAttribute = attribute as PXSomeAttribute;
    if (someAttribute != null) 
    {
        someAttribute.Property = someValue;
    }
}
```

**Way 2**

A less verbose / arguably more readable way of achieving the same goal with LINQ:

```
cache
    .GetAttributes<Field>(dataRecord)
    .OfType<PXSomeAttribute>()
    .ForEach(attribute => attribute.Property = someValue);
```

Source: http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/05/dynamically-changing-attribute-property.html.